# Manipulate matrixs in r

Tags: r, matrix

I have this matrix M1

```
userid videoid rate
U1        V1      5        
U2        V1      3
U3        V2      2
```

And I need to transform it to this forma but i dont know how to do it

```
    V1    V2
 U1  5     NA
 U2  3     NA
 U3  NA    2
```

I tried :

```
for (i in 1 :nrow(M1))
 M2 [M1[i,1],M1[1,i]] <- M1[i,3]
```

It is not working of course, but if it does, it wont give me the needed result. any suugestion will be of a great help

Comment: This is a very basic `?reshape`.  And that looks more like a data frame than a matrix.  What is the `class` of the structure?

Comment: Basically it s a data frame with more than the 3 columns cited ( userid, videoid, and rate),  I exported them to matrix to be able to use the for loop .. ps: I just start using R

Comment: `library(reshape2);dcast(df, userid ~ videoid)`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want ?

```
 library(reshape2)
 acast(df, userid~videoid, value.var="rate")

   V1 V2
U1  5 NA
U2  3 NA
U3 NA  2
```

Comment: partially yes, I get the right shape but the cells are filled with the wrong rate and this warning " Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length"

Comment: it is all base on your example data~ Maybe you have different data format in your real data ?

Comment: Actually I am working with a large dataset, the only problem i can think about is having the same (userid, videoid ) with different rate. 
Maybe i should test with some rows only.

Comment: Could you please show me the example of you data ? Maybe I can help

Comment: it's a dataframe (280x280) of integer for the userID and videoID , float for rates. and i dont have any empty cell. After using acast , i m getting a dataframe (17x80) of zeros and 2

Comment: anyway, I will suggest open a new question and show the demo of your real dataframe and your desired output